# Adding the number of comments to a queryset in Django

Tags: python, django, comments

I want to display a post along with the number of comments in Django. I don't currently have the number of comments a post as in the Post model, I was thinking I would be able to write some kind of model function to show how many comments a post has without putting in something like `comment_count` in the model.

Here is my Post model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=False)
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=400, verbose_name="post headline")
    type = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    branch = models.ForeignKey(Branch, verbose_name="branch name", validators=[branch_exists])
    upvotes = models.IntegerField()
    is_starred = models.BooleanField()
    url_title = models.SlugField()
    creation = models.DateTimeField()
    thumbnail = models.URLField(blank=True)
    body = models.TextField(max_length=90000, blank=False)
    link = models.URLField(blank=False, verbose_name="your link URL")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"`%s' posted by %s at %s\n" % (self.headline, self.user, self.creation)
```

And here is my Comment model:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique="False")
    time = models.DateTimeField()
    upvotes = models.IntegerField()
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, unique="False")
    formatting = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Format comment?")
    text = models.TextField(max_length=9000, blank=False)
    anonymous = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Post comment anonymously?")
```

I want to do something like:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return u"`%s' posted by %s at %s with %s comments" % (self.headline, self.user, self.creation, self.comment_count)
```

but without a comment_count field; I want the number of comments to be pulled from the database along with the Post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Annotations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/)... apparently Django's best-kept secret:

```
from django.db.models import Count
Post.objects.annotate(comment_count=Count('comment'))
```

Then, each instance will have a `comment_count` attribute you can use.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the comments associated with the post using the `comment_set` attribute (this is the default, if you set `related_name` on your `post` ForeignKey on your `Comment` model, you can make it something else). To just retrieve the count, use `self.comment_set.count()`.

The Django documentation has a section on this underneath [Following relationships backward](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects).